# job is running but sidekiq queue is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sidekiq

I am trying to figure out how I can access the status of the background job using sidekiq.

To check the status of the job I check the size of the queue.

```
class PagesWorker
    include Sidekiq::Worker
    include Sidekiq::Status::Worker

    sidekiq_options queue: "high"

    def perform(ifile)
        system "rake db:..."

        # What do the following do? In what scenario would I need to set these?
        total 100
        at 5, "Almost done"
        store vino: 'veritas'
        vino = retrieve :vino
    end
end

class PagesController
    def submit
        job_id = SomeWorker.perform_async(file)
        flash[:notice] = "#{job_id} is being processed."
    end

    def finished
        queue = Sidekiq::Status.new('high')
        if queue.size == 0
           flash[:success] = "Job is finished."
        elsif queue.size > 0
           flash[:notice] = "Job is being processed."
        end
    end
end
```

It prints "Job is finished" from the start (while the job is still running) because the queue is always zero. Specifically, in myrailsapp/sidekiq page I see the following:

- The number of processed jobs increments by one every time I submit a job, which is correct.
- The 'high' queue is there but its size is always 0, which isn't correct.
- And there are no jobs listed under the queue, which again isn't correct.

However the job is being processed and finishes successfully. Could the reason for the job not appearing in the sidekiq page be that the job finishes in less that a minute? Or maybe because the worker runs a rake process?

I have also checked the following in the terminal, while the process is running:

```
Sidekiq::Status::complete? job_id #returns false
Sidekiq::Status::status(job_id) #returns nothing
Sidekiq::Status::get_all job_id #returns {"update_time"=>"1458063970", "total"=>"100", "at"=>"5", "message"=>"Almost done"}, and after a while returns {}
```

To sum up, my queue is empty, my jobs list is empty, but my job is running. How is this possible? What can I do to track the status of my job?

**EDIT**

I use the job status to check whether it is finished or not.

Controller:

```
def finished
    job_id = params[:job_id]
    if Sidekiq::Status::complete? job_id == true
       flash[:notice] = "Job is finished."
    elsif Sidekiq::Status::complete? job_id == false
       flash[:notice] = "Job is being processed."
    end
end
```

Form:

```
=form_tag({action: :submit},multipart: true) do # submit is my controller method as defined above
    = file_field_tag 'file'
    = submit_tag 'submit'

=flash[:notice] # defined above as "#{job_id} is being processed."
-job_id = flash[:notice].split(" ")[0]
=form_tag({action: :finished}) do
    = hidden_field_tag 'job_id', job_id
    = submit_tag 'check'
```

Routes:

```
 resources :pages do
     collection do
        post 'submit' 
        post 'finished'
     end
 end
```

But the Sidekiq::Status::complete? job_id never turns to true. I am tailing the log file to see when the process will finish, and click on the check button but still get that it is still getting processed. Why?

Comment: Enqueued means that Sidekiq has not started working on the job yet. It is removed from the queue so it can be processed.

Comment: I see thank you! That means that I cannot use queue size to get the status of the job. But this returns me to another problem. How can I pass the job_id to the controller's finished method? I will update the post with my form.

Comment: I guess you don't understand Sidekiq: the job is async.  It might finish 2 sec or 2 hours from now.  You don't know.  If you want to see real-time status, you should have the job set a flag in Redis and use websockets or poll with JS.

Comment: I understand that the job will finish in an x amount of time. What I am trying to do is the user to check the status of the job by pushing a button. This button will call the finished method which will check if the job is complete by Sidekiq::Status::complete? job_id. But Sidekiq::Status::complete? job_id never turns to true, why?

Comment: I don't know, I don't write Sidekiq::Status.

Comment: How do you check the job status then?

Comment: The job itself must update the database.  You would check the database.

Comment: Simple and right! Thank you for your idea!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you are using sidekiq-status gem and you can use the following way

https://github.com/utgarda/sidekiq-status#retrieving-status

If you just wanted to know if the job is queued, then you may stop running the sidekiq process and simply send the job using the sidekiq client and from there you can list the queues in the redis-cli like

```
$ redis-cli
> select 0 # (or whichever namespace Sidekiq is using)
> keys * # (just to get an idea of what you're working with)
> smembers queues
> lrange queues:app_queue 0 -1
> lrem queues:app_queue -1 "payload"
```

and see if the job is queued and once after starting the sidekiq process again, you would see the job being processed and you can puts in the perform method also and that too would be printed in the logs of the sidekiq.

Comment: I am using the sidekiq-status indeed and I have been following the same link you provided. The only reason I used queue is to check if my job is still running. I hadn't realized that when it is running it will be out of the queue anyway. But what I really want is when clicking the 'check' button, to get a message if the job is finished or not.